# How can I deploy SSRS reports to report server without debugging report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-data-tools, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

How can I deploy rdl files with SSDT solution without debugging rdl file, so that I can avoid the data set or data source error.

Its a kind of a rdl files migration, without using any rs.exe kind of utility.

Its working so far, but each time I have to create a new data source & there are lots of reports & data sources. I want to avoid this & only deploy rdl files. Please suggest an easy way, without any coding, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You Can open the Report Manager , click on "Upload" button on the right side , select your RDL file and you are done .